# Cannot setup NameCheap domain with Github Pages. Getting error emails that says "CNAME already taken"

Tags: github, dns, github-pages

I have Github Pages setup correctly but am unable to connect it to my custom domain name. Below is an image of the Advanced DNS settings page on NameCheap. I also have a text file called CNAME that contains "mywebsite.com" in the Github.io repository.

After settings things up, I also got an error email from Github that says

`"The page build completed successfully, but returned the following warning: 
CNAME already taken"`

[image: Advanced DNS Settings]

Comment: Why are you hiding informations needed to debug ? Repository url, domain name.

Comment: is this still a issue?